# C# DataTable: Add missing dates

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable with the following structure:

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2MIi.png)

What I'm trying to do is for every username I have to fill in the gaps for the whole month for the "Logdate" column, like in above table the username "Test" should have entries from 12/01/2015 till 12/31/2015 with a Sale value of 0, since two entries exist for the month already those shouldn't be added.

Comment: The reason is the DataTable gets the data from the database, it doesn't have entries sometimes for some days in the month.

Comment: Use LINQ and a Range for the full month, deselect the dates already present, add the remaining to the DataTable.

Comment: I seems rather straight forward. What have you tried?

Comment: I looped through the table and checked if next row has the date of (current row date + 1 day), if not then add a row at i + 1 position, the problem is the table isn't sorted by username so that wouldn't work.

Comment: Also I just can't get LINQ to work, maybe because I'm on VS 2008, but the result of the LINQ isn't a DataTable I tried many things to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Username", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Logdate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Sale", typeof(decimal));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Test", DateTime.Parse("12/03/2015"), 4.5 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Test", DateTime.Parse("12/13/2015"), 15 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Test2", DateTime.Parse("12/18/2015"), 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Test2", DateTime.Parse("12/25/2015"), 40 });

            Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("UserName"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

            foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
            {
                List<int> days = dict[key].Select(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Logdate").Day).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
                int month = dict[key].Select(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Logdate").Month).FirstOrDefault();
                int year = dict[key].Select(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Logdate").Year).FirstOrDefault();

                int lastDay = (new DateTime(year, month, 1)).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).Day;
                for (int day = 1; day <= lastDay; day++)
                {
                    if(!days.Contains(day))
                    {
                       dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { key, new DateTime(year, month, day), 0 });
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks :) I will try it tomorrow when I get to the PC